# WPF - MeasureOverride - TextBox does not autosize anymore

Tags: wpf, textbox, autosize, measureoverride

I have encountered a rather interesting problem. One of my user controls contains a label, a StackPanel which will contain further controls and a TextBox for a comment. The controls in the StackPanel may vary so I've set the Window to AutoSize. Works like a charm, no matter which controls are inside the Panel the Window is sized in width to display them all.

Now our UI designer has got the idea that the TextBox should not stretch the control. Meaning if there is a long text inside it it should not stretch the Window but just wrap. Making the StackPanel the control to determine the Window size.

So I've overwritten the MeasureOverride method on the user control to not add the TextBox width. Seems to be working on first glance. But the Window does not grow properly anymore. Press enter and the Window does not get adjusted to display the now bigger UserControl / TextBox.

I have looked at the [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and don't really see what I have missed. The reference source for TextBox and StackPanel did not bring enlightenment either.

Any suggestions?

UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MeasureOverrideTest.uc1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="Auto">

    <StackPanel>

        <Label Name="_label" Content="control title ... foo ... bar ..." />
        <StackPanel Name="_panel" Background="Aqua" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="20"></StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="_textBox" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLines="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>

    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

UserControl xaml.cs

```
public partial class uc1 : UserControl
{
    public uc1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var desiredSize = new Size();

        //business as usual
        _label.Measure(constraint);
        desiredSize.Width = Math.Max(desiredSize.Width, _label.DesiredSize.Width);
        desiredSize.Height += _label.DesiredSize.Height;

        //business as usual
        _panel.Measure(constraint);
        desiredSize.Width = Math.Max(desiredSize.Width, _panel.DesiredSize.Width);
        desiredSize.Height += _panel.DesiredSize.Height;

        //do not stretch the control, just take what is there
        _textBox.Measure(constraint); //first try: does not grow in height
        //_textBox.Measure(new Size(desiredSize.Width, constraint.Height)); //second try: not better
        desiredSize.Height += _textBox.DesiredSize.Height;

        //do not exceed the given limits
        desiredSize.Width = Math.Min(desiredSize.Width, constraint.Width);
        desiredSize.Height = Math.Min(desiredSize.Height, constraint.Height);

        return desiredSize;
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="MeasureOverrideTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MeasureOverrideTest"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:uc1 Grid.Row="0"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="buttons and stuff ...."/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Oh and btw. i know i can just bind the TextBox.MaxWidth to the Panel.ActualWidth and get the desired result. But i really can not explain why MeasureOverride should not work like expected.

Comment: How is this supposed to work at all? You are not measuring the top-level StackPanel in the Content of the UserControl. Maybe replace that StackPanel by a [custom Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Why would i measure that? It's just the container and therefore as big as the controls it contains

Comment: Why? Because you have to. Measure and arrange go over all elements in the visual tree. You can't simply skip elements. And you can of course only measure and arrange direct child elements, not any grandchildren.

Comment: That seems weird to me. If I call Measure on the top-level StackPanel it will iterate over all children and then the TextBox will once again demand the width to fit all the text in one line.

Comment: Anyhow. Even if I do that it still does not work. 

`protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)` 
`{`
`_parentPanel.Measure(constraint);`
`return new Size(_parentPanel.DesiredSize.Width, _parentPanel.DesiredSize.Height);`
` } ` 

That is what the base implementation would do if I understand correctly. But the Window does not adjust in height anymore. So we are back to the question: why?